# Hierarchical Nav just to Main Controller in Apple WatchKit 2

Tags: swift, watchkit

I am building an app which moves between a set of controllers using:

```
self.pushControllerWithName("Scene A", context: nil)
```

Calling this will create a Back ability at the top that is ideal e.g. Main Scene -> Scene A -> Scene B -> Scene C, however how can I pop the whole stack back to Main Scene from Scene C in a "pop to beginning" type call?  The only function I can see is this which only goes backwards one step.

```
self.popController()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is  also

```
self.popToRootController()
```

> **Discussion** Use this method to return your interface to its initial
>   configuration. You might do this so that you can reset your navigation
>   hierarchy to its initial state before pushing one or more different
>   interface controllers onto the navigation stack.
>
> Always call this method from your WatchKit extension’s main thread.
>
> Availability Available in iOS 8.2 and later.

[Reference Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceController/popToRootController)